# How to use 'get lost' to mean 'get lost'?

Tags: word-choice

Undoubtedly, I have heard this zillions of times since my childhood.

> [get lost](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/get-lost) -  used to tell someone forcefully and quite rudely to go away

Now, look at this campaign sentence -

> The soothing music of subliminal language takes you to the eternal journey of your soul. It's mind refreshing and rejuvenating. You **get lost** into the world of serenity and divineness.

*Get lost...* huh? I literally mean that *you really lose yourself into the world...*

Is it proper to use *get lost* there? Still, I want other alternative that should mean **one loses themselves into that world.**

Comment: Not really an answer, but I understand "get lost" as two words "get" and "lost". It's just that "Get lost!" is used in a specific (and quite rude) meaning. I think it should be *"get lost in the world of ..."* or *"lose yourself (in)to the world of ..."*

Comment: The 2nd meaning is also idiomatic. See _[lose oneself in](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lose+oneself+in)._

Answer (score 15):

The meaning of *get lost* as *bugger off* only applies when you use it as an **imperative**.

In the sentence

> You get lost into the world of serenity and divineness.

There is no imperative to be found, so the idiomatic meaning of the *imperative* "get lost!" does not apply.

You *could*, if you really wanted to, change the meaning of the phrase with a simple comma:

> You, get lost into the world of serenity and divineness.

But that would be stretching it. It does't really make sense to order someone to get lost in such a nice environment.

Even when used as an imperative, the "bugger off" meaning is not there unless context makes it very clear that it is mean to be rude.

As Damkerng T. notes, you could write:

> Get lost into the world of serenity and divineness.

meaning

> Lose yourself in the world of serenity and divineness.

To get lost usually simply means that you lose you way around somewhere - it only means that you should remove yourself literally off the premises when it is used as an imperative, standing on its own.

Comment: +1 for the concept of **imperative**. that's nice input.

Comment: or reported speech: *I told him to get lost*

Comment: or subjunctive: *I wish he would get lost*

Comment: @smci but not always: *I wish he would get lost in the music* (OK, a little contrived)

Comment: Sure, my point was simply to correct @oerkelens: *get lost* as *bugger off* only applies when you use it as an **imperative**.

Answer (score 4):

I find "get lost into" a bit clumsy - I'd rather hear "get lost in".

Comment: I purposely used **into** as it's moving from one place to another which generally takes **into**. Milk pour **into** the jar from a bottle.

Comment: @MaulikV, while I think you are technically correct, it still sounds wrong to me :)

Comment: http://books.google.co.in/books?id=7cL1mkQ48WcC&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=%22lost+into+another+world%22&source=bl&ots=C6tnUek_Et&sig=qzLqOtIIgo5KbGj8wJsZ_QIZRdo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=05A-U4W_BoqPrge_u4GQBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22lost%20into%20another%20world%22&f=false

Comment: @MaulikV It could sound wrong. Based on your link to the book, I tweaked the search a little: "lost into another world" returns 10 results, "lost in another world" returns 16,600 results, "get lost into another world" returns 3 results, and "get lost in another world" returns 341 results.

Comment: @DamkerngT. We are discussing about the word being **wrong** and not *popular* I guess. As far as *get lost into* is concerned, that's what the question is.

Comment: @MaulikV "Be lost **to**" is sometimes used. *"...was lost to the world of serenity"* could be said from the perspective of the people of the outside world, describing someone who is no longer connected to them.

Comment: Into sounds wrong, and I'd suggest that you're not in fact moving from one place to another. eg you might say 'Go into another world and lose yourself in it' - 'into' for the transition to another world, and 'in' for what happens when you get there.

Comment: “Get lost into” isn't idiomatic and grates on my ears and, I suspect, those of any native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the use of "get lost" may sound awkward in the sentence, though correct.

*lose your way* may be an alternative or *find a new dimension* can also fit the spirit of the ad.